# Date Time Picker Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datetimepicker

I'm creating a program in Visual Studio 2012. I have a date & time picker on the form and a button. Button enabled is currently set to false. When the date in the date & time picker is 3 months less than the current month I'd like to enable the button. E.g the current month is November, so if the selected date was August or earlier the button would be enabled. How would I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or...

```
Button1.Enabled = If(DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, DateTimePicker1.Value, Now) > 2, True, False)
```

Comment: No problems Luke! Glad I could help. Feel free to mark whichever Reply you like as the "Answer", and "Up-Vote" anything you find helpful! ;-) Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    Button1.Enabled = Not (DateTimePicker1.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date Or _
                          (DateTimePicker1.Value.AddMonths(2).Date = DateTime.Now.Date Or _
                           DateTimePicker1.Value.AddMonths(1).Date = DateTime.Now.Date))
End Sub
```

I expect you compare `dates only`. In order to include time too, you can remove `.Date` part from the code. Also we should also consider the `year` along with the `month`.